# Set RestAngular default request parameters after login

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm hitting an API which requires all authenticated actions to include an auth token in the request, however, I do not have the auth token until I login.

I've only seen examples of setting default request parameters in Restangular in `app.config`.
Is it possible to set this until after the user has logged in and `User.auth_token` is set?

So basically instead of:

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams({
        auth_token: 'thisistheauthenticationtoken'
    });
});
```

I need:

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams({
        auth_token: User.auth_token
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you get to solve this?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue...any progress? (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you set token as part of the response versus in the header? Like so.

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({ authentication: 'bearer ' + token.authentication });
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but this SO question kept appearing when I was Googling (yes, I just used Google as a verb... deal with it :P) for a resolution, so I thought I should provide my solution. Hopefully it will help the OP or anyone else that may come across this page.

```
angular.module("app").factory("UserService", [
    "$rootScope",
    "$state",
    "$q",
    "Restangular",
    function ($rootScope, $state, $q, Restangular) {
        var UserSvc = {};
        var Identity;

        /*
            This creates a scoped copy of Restangular
            Normally this is where you would use setDefaultRequestParams,
            but it would only affect this scope and not ALL API requests in your app
         */
        var UsersAPI = Restangular.withConfig(function (RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl("api/1.0/users");
        });

        UserSvc.login = function (credentials) {
            var $defer = $q.defer();

            UsersAPI.all("start-session").post(credentials).then(function(respData){
                if (respData.apikey) {
                    Identity = respData.plain();

                    /*
                        User is authenticated and API key is obtained from server response

                        Note how I do NOT use the setDefaultRequestParams function:
                        If we do the withConfig/setDefaultRequestParams, it only affects local scope, not global
                        This method modifies the ROOT Restangular object and
                        will then propegate through all future use of Restangular in your app
                     */
                    Restangular.configuration.defaultRequestParams.common.apikey = Identity.apikey;


                    if ($rootScope.toState && $rootScope.toState.name != "login") {
                        $state.go($rootScope.toState.name, $rootScope.toStateParams || {});
                    } else {
                        $state.go("app.dashboard");
                    }

                    $defer.resolve(Identity);
                }
                else {
                    Identity = undefined;

                    $defer.reject(Identity);
                }
            },function (respData) {
                $defer.reject(respData);
            });

            return $defer.promise;

        };

        return UserSvc;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use

```
Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams({token: localstorage.get('token')});
```

This works with me. Please have a look my snippet here.
https://github.com/fugokidi/ng-snippets/blob/master/rest.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this, you need to remove your code from app.cofig and move to when you find user is logged in.

You can set defaultRestParams for restangular at any point of application using Restangular service.

For more info refer https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaultrequestparams.

Comment: I've tried moving those lines after the `auth_token` is available but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

A more Angular-ish example from a project that I've been working on:

```javascript
angular.module('app', [ 'restangular' ])
  .factory('API', function(Restangular){
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(config){
      config
        .setBaseUrl('https://api.example.com')
        // etc etc etc
      ; // END config
    });
  })
  .factory('Auth', function(API){
    return {
      login: function(credentials){
        // Assuming I just POST /session/new to get an OAuth token,
        // which is totally not a thing that OAuth should do.
        API.one('session').post('new', credentials)
          .then(function(auth){ // Assuming `auth = { access_token: '...' }`
            API.setDefaultHeaders({
              Authorization: 'bearer ' + auth.access_token
              // Assuming OAuth Bearer Token
            });
          })
      },
      logout: function(){ /* . . . */ }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainController', function(API, Auth){
    var self = this;

    self.user = { };

    this.login = function(credentials){
      Auth.login(credentials).then(function(){
        self.user = API.one('user').$object;
      });
    });
  })
; // END module(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will read the token from storage for every request.

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

    //Injext $cookies manually (there might be better ways to do this)
    var $cookies;
    angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
        $cookies = _$cookies_;
    }]);

    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
        Authorization: function() {
            return $cookies.get('token');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this.
Instead of using

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams({
    auth_token: 'thisistheauthenticationtoken'
});
```

try using

```
Restangular.setDefaultRequestParams({auth_token:'thisistheauthenticationtoken'});
```